# magento 2.4 issue creating configurable product programmatically

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.4, object-manager

i am using the below code to create a configurable product from product sku (from attributes color and size), it is working fine when all associated products have both attributes - color and size

Issue comes one Attribute is not there in all associated product.

For eg

**Case 1: works fine**

SKU 1 : Size - L and Color - Red

SKU 2 : Size -M and Color - Black

**Case 2: Add to cart not working as both associated product have one attribute Color missing as both associated product**

SKU 1 : Size - L

SKU 2 : Size -M

**Case 3: Add to cart not working as both associated product have one attribute Size missing as both associated product**

SKU 1 : Color - Red

SKU 2 : Color - Black

**Also i get the below error in the admin when I try to edit the configurable product in **CASE 2** and **CASE 3****

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /usr/share/nginx/zodiac/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/VariationMatrix.php on line 49
Exception in /usr/share/nginx/zodiac/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
```

**Code as below :**

```
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $product->setTypeId('configurable') 
            ->setStatus(1) // 1 = enabled, 2 = disabled
            ->setAttributeSetId(4) // 4 = default
            ->setName('Configurable test product')
            ->setSku('config')
            ->setPrice(0)
            ->setTaxClassId(2) // 0 = None, 2 = Default product tax class
            ->setCategoryIds(array(2)) // 2 = Default category
            ->setDescription('test description')
            ->setShortDescription('test short description')
            ->setUrlKey('configurable-test-product')
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) // 1 = Default Website ID
            ->setStoreId(0) // 0 = Default store ID
            ->setVisibility(4); // 4 = Catalog & Search
                    
    $product_resource = $product->getResource();
    $color_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('color');
    $size_attribute = $product_resource->getAttribute('size');
    $color_attribute_id = $color_attribute->getId();
    $size_attribute_id = $size_attribute->getId();
    $configurable_attributes = array('color', 'size'); // put here all configurable attributes you need and get their attribute IDs like I showed above
    $product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($color_attribute_id, $size_attribute_id), $product); // assign attributes to configurable product
    
    $configurable_attributes_data = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
    $product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurable_attributes_data);
    
    $child_product_skus = array('SKU1','SKU2');
    $child_ids = array();
    foreach ($child_product_skus as $child_product) {
        echo "<br>".$child_product;
        $child_ids[] = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku($child_product);
    }
    print_r($child_ids);
    $product->setAssociatedProductIds($child_ids);
    $product->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tricky solution to this was:

1: after running code i, did exported them as csv

2: detelted all configurable products

3: reimported them from cms

and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

> Install php extension

```
sudo apt-get install php-sodium
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Code `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php :: setUsedProductAttributeIds()`

[image: OOTB setUsedProductAttributeIds() Code]

My (best) guess is that - if/when you try to bind a null value to a Product_Attribute - Magento ends up throwing in the Towel.

To rule this out:

(a) Check if the Product_Attributes `size` and `color` are setup as MANDATORY parameters

(b) Check if the `$color_attribute_id` and `$size_attribute_id` params have valid value-binding (using `isset()`) before you try to map/assign it to the product.